# How do I preprocess/run a .js file in Atom?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

Given the following file, and a newly downloaded version of Atom 1.0, how do I preprocess / run it?

```
"use babel";

function* count(n){
    console.log(n);
}
```

The "use babel" is as per [this post](http://blog.atom.io/2015/02/04/built-in-6to5.html) on the Atom blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pragma is related to creating packages in atom. If you want to transpile using babel you need to use the babel CLI or another method (task runner: grunt, gulp i.e).